# SSJS Init and Retrieve methods not working

Tags: marketing-cloud, salesforce1-app, ssjs

Basically I'm creating a script that retrieves all subscribers from a custom DE and unsubscribe them from the AllSubscribers. This code is going to be used inside a Script Activity which will execute daily.

The problem comes when I try to use the main function DataExtension.Init(). I've been using this method since the day I started to program in SSJS, but It doesn't work anymore.

My code:

```js
<script runat="server">
    Platform.Load("Core","1.1.1");
    
    try{
    
      var myDE = DataExtension.Init("ExternalKey");
      var rows = myDE.Rows.Retrieve();

      Write("Rows: " + rows)
      
    }catch(error){
      Write("<br>error: " + Stringify(error));
    }
</script>
```

My DE has only 2 columns: **ContactID** and **Email**. It is non-sendable(I also tried to change it in sendable=true but nothing happend!). I also printed the object Retrieve and I noticed the method Rows.Retrieve doesn't exists anymore(the documentation do not mention this).

Are these methods still supported? Am I missing anything?

Comment: The code works fine for me. I just switched the core library to 1 instead of 1.1.1. Also retrieved the rows for a non sendable DE. Also, I have write as  Write("Rows: " + Stringify(rows)). Ran the code on a cloud page

Comment: Looking at your another question, I suspect Init does not work, since you are trying to initiate your All Subscribers list as a Data Extension

Comment: How should I fix my code? I tried to do "List.Init" but it blocks me when I try to update records inside of it with this row:
allSubs.Rows.Update({Status: "Unsubscribed"}, ["SubscriberKey"], subKey);
Where "subKey" it's a variable that has all the subscriberKey I want to unsubscribe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The row set you was trying to retrieve in the DE is an array data, you cannot use Write function to "print" like that.

Try this:

```JavaScript
<script runat="server">
    Platform.Load("Core","1.1.1");
    
    try{
    
      var myDE = DataExtension.Init("ExternalKey");
      var rows = myDE.Rows.Retrieve();
      Write(Stringify(rows));
      Write("<br>Rows: " + rows.length)
      
    }catch(error){
      Write("<br>error: " + Stringify(error));
    }
</script>
```

Here is the [document](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/ssjs_dataExtensionRowsRetrieve.html) for the method `Rows.Retrieve`